# Como normalizar esse pequeno Banco de Dados?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, entidade-relacionamento

Estou tentando melhorar esse pequeno banco de dados do eu TCC do técnico, ele é bem pequeno, é de uma pequena página para um comércio, em que eu teria um catálogo de produtos e promoções para atrair compradores para a loja física. Espero que possam me dar algumas dicas.

[image: Modelo Relacional - Catálogo de produtos]

Comment: Subcategoria e Categoria poderiam ser uma tabela só e as imagens poderiam está em outra tabela.

Comment: No caso, categoria teria q ser unica e as sub-categorias só podem repetir de nome se forem relacionadas a outra categoria, como isso ficaria?

Comment: Você pode utilizar uma coluna chamada `parent_id`. Essa coluna levaria o valor do ID da categoria (caso fosse uma subcategoria). Caso essa coluna seja 0 = categoria pai; caso seja maior que 0 = categoria filho. [Exemplo](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/1ae5de207d26eee688fbf3e2d67cc05515ade3a9/upload/install/opencart.sql#L342-L355)

Comment: Incrível! Ótima solução! Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Começando com o comentário do Valdeir Psr, As tabelas "categoria" e "subcategoria" seriam uma só tabela. Haveria um campo `parent_id` que seria `NULLABLE` referenciando a categoria pai.

Para impedir que categorias se repitam, coloque uma `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` em `nome` e `parent_id` em conjunto.

Deveria haver uma tabela de imagens. Não sei se você pode ter diferentes produtos com a mesma imagem. Se puder, o relacionamento entre "imagem" e "produto" seria N:N, senão seria 1:N. Vou presumir que é N:N.

Na tabela "promocao", não recomendaria usar `float` para o preço. Sugiro `NUMERIC(10, 2)` ou coisa similar.

Ficaria assim:

```
CREATE TABLE categoria (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  parent_id INT(11) NULL,
  nome VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  ativo TINYINT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_categoria PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_categoria_parent FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES categoria (id),
  CONSTRAINT uk_categoria UNIQUE (parent_id, nome)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE imagem (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nome VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_imagem PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE produto (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  categoria_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  nome VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,
  descricao TEXT(3000) NOT NULL,
  data_entrada DATE NOT NULL,
  ativo TINYINT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_produto PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_produto_categoria FOREIGN KEY (categoria_id) REFERENCES categoria (id),
  CONSTRAINT uk_produto UNIQUE (nome)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE produto_imagem (
  produto_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  imagem_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_produto_imagem PRIMARY KEY (produto_id, imagem_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_produto_imagem_produto FOREIGN KEY (produto_id) REFERENCES produto (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_produto_imagem_imagem FOREIGN KEY (imagem_id) REFERENCES imagem (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE promocao (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  produto_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  preco NUMERIC(10, 2) NOT NULL,
  validade DATE NULL,
  obs VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_promocao PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_promocao_produto FOREIGN KEY (produto_id) REFERENCES produto (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4;
```

Answer (score 1):

Aroveitando a resposta anterior eu faria algumas modificações. Explico:

Não existe certo ou errado ao normalizar um DB. Quando estamos na faculdade, parece que o "certo" é normalizar o máximo possível e mostrar para o professor que sabemos analisar o todo em pequenas partes.

No mundo real é preciso considerar performance, por exemplo. Mas não apenas isso: o layout que será imposto ao banco, ou a alteração que será feita nesse layout, pode impor grandes custos de manutenção de código das aplicações que acessam esse banco, de procedures ou functions do próprio banco ... e tempo e dinheiro são coisas que não se entendem bem ao programar uma solução.

Pra resumir: às vezes é preciso confiar que algumas "não normalizações" são a melhor saída. No seu caso, eu assumi que o Analista está seguro que seu produto terá entre nenhuma ou até 3 imagens. Pressuponho que não será interessante, por uma questão de performance, salvar a imagem como um BLOB na tabela e sim como um nome ou caminho para encontrá-lo no sistema de arquivos, numa nuvem, numa montagem FTP, SSH ...

Concordo que a categoria e sub categoria são um "composite". Deixar na mesma tabela me parece melhor, eu sempre faço isso e nunca tive motivo para fazer diferente.

Por outro lado, criar tabelas de imagem, ou seja, "normalizar demais" terá um custo quando o banco estiver em produção. Com o conhecimento que tenho hoje, eu perderia menos esforço normalizando o banco e justificaria no meu TCC que o impacto dos diversos JOINs não justifica criar tabelas de imagem, pois o Analista também está seguro que não haverá mais de 3 imagens por produto.

```
CREATE TABLE categoria (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  parent_id INT(11) NULL,
  nome VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  ativo TINYINT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_categoria PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_categoria_parent FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES categoria (id),
  CONSTRAINT uk_categoria UNIQUE (parent_id, nome)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4;


CREATE TABLE produto (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  categoria_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  nome VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,
  descricao TEXT(3000) NOT NULL,
  imagem1 VARCHAR(255),
  imagem2 VARCHAR(255),
  imagem3 VARCHAR(255),
  data_entrada DATE NOT NULL,
  ativo TINYINT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_produto PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_produto_categoria FOREIGN KEY (categoria_id) REFERENCES categoria (id),
  CONSTRAINT uk_produto UNIQUE (nome)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4;


CREATE TABLE promocao (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  produto_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  preco NUMERIC(10, 2) NOT NULL,
  validade DATE NULL,
  obs VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_promocao PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_promocao_produto FOREIGN KEY (produto_id) REFERENCES produto (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: O problema é que futuramente isso pode ser mudado. Uma tabela somente para imagens, deixa o usuário escolher, mais livremente, quantas imagens ele quer. No quesito manutenção e legibilidade, na minha opinião, é uma boa alternativa.